# How to view data from NSTextField Correctly?

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield

Hi i've recently completed a tutorial book on the basics of objective c. And now I'm "Attempting" to make a simple application. Right now I seem to be having the simplest issues which i cannot seem to fix, maybe you could tell me what i'm doing incorrectly.

## AppDelegate.h

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

    @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

    @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
    - (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender;
    //Below is a simple IBOutlet which I try to retrieve data from when the IBAction saveData occurs
    @property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *foodName;


    @end
```

## AppDelegate.m

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }
    //Here is the saveData IBAction which should print out the value of the NSTextField if the user entered a value (if not returns null)
    - (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"%@", foodName.stringValue);
        NSLog(@"Saved");
    }
    @end
```

The problem I seem to have is the build will fail and give me an error message on this line in AppDelegate.m:

```
    NSLog(@"%@", foodName.stringValue);
```

the error message is: Use of undeclared identifier 'foodName'; did you mean '_foodName'?

Could someone please explain whats going on and how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *address* the getter method, use `self.`:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.foodName.stringValue);
```

Also, a minor point: group all your `@property` declarations together at the start of the `@interface` statement, but after any instance variable declarations:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSString *_str1;
    int _i1;
}
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSString *something;
@property (strong, readonly) NSNumber *somethingElse;
- (int)aMethod:(NSString *)string;
- (void)anotherMethod;
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, curious though why does it need self?

Comment: @Mutch95 You are using auto-generated instance variables where, by default, the instance variable is `_foodName` (as hinted at by the compiler error you posted).  To access a method (which is what the getter and setter are) you always need an object instance (`self` in this case), in the form `self.foodName` or `[self foodName]` or `[self setFoodName:]`.